# High latency with Spring multipart file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a Spring-boot project in which I have to send files (one at a time) through a REST Web Service to a server, which sends it to a Cassandra cluster.

This part works, but my problem appeared when I began to do stress tests (with Gatling) on my project.

Here it is :
    - When I tested my work without sending files, I had latency ~10-15 ms ;
    - When I tested my work sending a file in the body of the request, I had latency ~10-15 ms too (maybe a little higher by 5 or 10 ms, I don't remember);
    - BUT, and my problem shows up here, when I tested the Web Service by sending files with an `input`, and getting it with MultipartFile, the latency was very variable, from 10 ms for the fastest requests, to 12000ms (!!) for the longest.

I tried to set the files in memory limit to 1Go (it was originaly ~10ko), but it didn't change anything.
I don't get any error while executing the tests, it's just very long...

Plus, this project is being made to modernize the existing webservice, which runs as a JAX-WS, with WSDL and all. The team working on the old project (we are switching from a DBMS to an other) has response times of ~10 in mean !

Here's my conf (this is for a POC, the machines are cheap) :
    - Web server : Wildfly 9-0-1.FINAL out of the box, on CentOS Server 7.1;
    - Stress tests machine : Gatling 2.1.7, on the same CentOS version as Wildfly, but on an other machine;
    - An 8 nodes Cassandra cluster.

Here is my pom (without company's secrets | concerning the spring-boot dependency, it's not my project's parent, it already has one):

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-jfrog-artifactory</id>
        <name>oss-jfrog-artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

StartApp.java:

```
package foo.bar;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MultipartAutoConfiguration.class)
public class StartApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(StartApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 1Go
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

WS.java (only the relevant function) :

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import service.DaoException;
import service.ErrCode;
import service.IService;

...

@Inject IService service;

...

@RequestMapping(path = "/insert/{foo}/{bar}", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@PathVariable String foo,
        @PathVariable String bar,
        @RequestParam MultipartFile document) {

    HttpStatus httpCode = HttpStatus.CREATED;

    try (InputStream is = document.getInputStream()) {
            service.insert(foo, bar, is);
    } catch (DaoException e) {

        logger.error("Problème lors de l'insertion du document : "
                + e.getMessage());

        httpCode = handleError(e.getCode());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        logger.error("Problème lors du traitement du document envoyé : "
                + e1.getMessage());
        httpCode = handleError(ErrCode.PB_TECHNIQUE);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(httpCode).build();
}
```

Simulation.scala :

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.util.Base64
import java.io.File
import java.lang.String

class RestSimulation1 extends Simulation {

    val DEBIT = 30 //Clients per second
    val DUREE = 300 //Duration


    val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://myserver:8080") // Here is the root for all relative urls     
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // Here are the common headers
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")


    //Feeders creation
    val feeder = csv("9k_rest.csv").queue

    object Insert {

        val insert = feed(feeder)
        .exec(http("insertion")
        .post("/webservice/ws/insert/${fooo}/${bar}")
        .formUpload("document", "rest_insert_${format}.txt")
        .check(status.is(201)))
    }

    val scn = scenario("").exec(Insert.insert)

    setUp(scn.inject( constantUsersPerSec(DEBIT) during(DUREE seconds))).protocols(httpConf)


}
```

What do I do wrong ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: IMHO you are comparing apples and oranges... You are comparing a SOAP WS with a plain web approach. Those are different beasts. Also if you want performance you might want to do streaming uploads instead of parsing a `MultipartFile`. That also depends on how large your files are.

Comment: Yes but I thought a REST approach would be faster than a SOAP envelope, which adds a lot of data to the request.
How do I stream uploads ? My files are 100-150kB large.
EDIT : You mean putting the file in the request's body ?

Comment: With SOAP you have the fully prepared XML, now you are uploading a file. If it is large it takes a while as it is in memory, partially on disk, parsed to a `MultipartFile`. All those things you don't need with XML. For streaming disable multipart file processing and do [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) in your controller method.

Comment: Okay, I did what you said (I think), but my response times are still high af (245ms max, 154ms avg). Maybe I'm missing something ?
My code is here (I tried with @EnableAutoConfiguration and without it)
(If you want me to put it elsewhere for it to be more readable, just say it, I just don't know where to post it beside by answering my question)
http://pastebin.com/LuLxh6mE

Comment: That doesn't really disable `MultipartFile` parsing you still would need to exclude the auto configuration. Also make sure you don't log everything at debug. Slap a profiler on it to see where it is coming from (the latency). Or add `multipart.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`. Also why are you parsing the URL yourself? The `foo` and `bar` are already present as `@PathVariable`s and can be injected into your method automatically.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was part of the multipart handling, it put it back ^^
So, I put multipart.enabled=false in my src/resources/application.properties file, but it doesn't change the time my request takes to accomplish (I didn't put back the @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude...) annotation, do I need to uncomment it ? And if so, what classes do I need to exclude?
Also, how do I slap a profiler on my app ?
btw thank you very much !

Comment: Well if you include the `spring-boot-actuator` you already get some metrics. But you can use VisualVM to see what happens or if you want more insight something like yourkit will help. Or a simple poor man solution is to use AOP and use one of the Spring interceptors for the methods performance logging (which of course will impact performance al little).

Comment: So I did that, I don't know exactly which metric to analyse, it's a little messy :p
Unfortunatly, I won't be able to work on these servers starting from tonight, so I will stop working on it. Thank you for you help (again)